# Is the Ancient "font" based on any real language?

Tags: stargate

I know the ancient language itself is very similar/based on Latin, but is the text itself based on any known living or dead real script?

I don't think it looks like Latin at all.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Dunno about the ancient language (and I haven't watched SG1 for years) but I think I remember the Goa'uld language was actually used for a lot of inside jokes on the show; it can be translated -- [SG Wiki on it](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Kree_%28word%29)

Comment: @KeithHWeston I know the Ancient language also was used for jokes a lot in Atlantis.  Probably SG-1 as well.  I think I remember one translation of an Ancient tablet in SG-1 being something like "You are reading me now".

Comment: The numbers look like a cell phone battery indicator :)

Comment: Why would they also have 26 letters and 10 numbers if it was *not* an inside joke?

Comment: @Wikis Good point, especially considering that it seemed to be established that the Ancients used base 8 math.

Comment: @NominSim but do notice that the glyphs have 3 "bits" per line.. 111 -> 7. base 8 :) (necrocommenting!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There appears to be no information linking it to actual real life script.

One [quote](http://www.omniglot.com/writing/ancients.htm) I found stated (unsourced) that:

> The heavy, block style was inspired by a font used on a 1940s Czech propaganda poster.

---

Just to be clear - while the language itself is meant to be related to Latin (see below), **individual letters were NOT quite Latin alphabet. Instead, they were symbols that could be translated to Latin letters via a simple substitution cypher** (shown in your picture).

---

[Ancients article on the Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_%28Stargate%29#Language_and_writing_system) (Language and writing system section) says (emphasis mine):

> **The Ancients' language appears to be a precursor of Latin, but it is still distinct.** There are many similarities between the two languages, and someone with a decent knowledge of Latin may, given time and practice, be able to understand Ancient as well (src: "The Fifth Race")

The exact quote from the episode (from SG Wikia):

> As Daniel pointed out while Jack was still under the influence of the Ancient Repository: "The language he's speaking has similar sounds to medieval Latin but it's still quite different." (2.16 "Fifth Race").

[Dictionary](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/Ancient_Language#Ancient_to_English_Dictionary) is on Wikia.

... Furthermore,

> Passages written in Ancient on the shows can be transliterated into English (there are no characters for spaces and punctuation marks). These transliterations show that the in-show writing system rules do not necessarily apply in reality, but they sometimes reveal in-jokes or offer further (non-canon) information instead. For example, parts of the writings on Atlantis main screens include the beginning of the nursery rhyme Where Oh Where Has My Little Dog Gone?, and the text shown on Daniel's laptop in the episode "Affinity" can be transliterated into "Actual words are hard to deciph(er) so this(')ll work".
>
> Playback supervisor Krista McLean said that when she originally put the graphics together for the Atlantian holo screens, she carelessly used things that were going through her head. When fans translated the language on the internet, she became more careful and tried to not use direct English translations anymore. ([src](http://josephmallozzi.wordpress.com/2009/02/10/february-10-2009-hey-look-who-wasnt-trapped-under-a-refrigerator-for-the-past-two-months-after-all-stargate-playback-superviser-krista-mclean-finally-drops-in-to-answer-your-questions/): *Hey, Look Who Wasn't Trapped Under A Refrigerator For The Past Two Months After All! Stargate Playback Superviser Krista McLean Finally Drops In To Answer Your Questions.". Josephmallozzi's Weblog. 2009-02-10. Retrieved 2010-05-21.*)

Comment: One line relating to the question (the script/font) followed by several paragraphs that don't (the language).

Comment: "but is the text itself based on any known living or dead real script" -- I'd say he answered that quite well, both with a canon answer and a RL answer. +1

Comment: Latin, to my understanding looks like English characters. I do not agree that the Ancient language visually is similar to Latin. I think the word "appears" means "seems to be" not "is visual similar to"

Comment: @Pyrodante - visually, it looks to me to be very Hebrew as far as styling. Not sure if that was designer's intent

Comment: THANK YOU! I totally agree, my boss laughed at me when I saw something written in ancient, and I said it was Hebrew, now if only we could find some evidence of this.

Comment: @NickT - I think that the original wording of the question that I saw didn't state the word "font" in the subject - either I missed it or it was edited in later. Either way, I added more info, see if that satisfies you to remove the downvote. Thx

Comment: If I didn't know different I'd also say it's Hebrew. IMO, they don't look like either Latin or Cyrillic letters at all, however they do look like [Angular Glagolitic](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Angular_Glagolitic_letters) letters a little, mostly because they are, well.. so angular.

Comment: @GoranJovic Those look like the Ancient number puzzle from Season 9 Episode 1...

Answer (score 3):

DVK has a pretty exhaustive direct answer to your question. I thought I'd add a little bit from an amateur linguist's point of view. I have never seen the show, and know nothing about it beyond the movie (which I did see) - this, I think, is actually good.

This script bears a clear "maker's mark", where it's clear that the script evolved as a consequence of the means of making it. If I were really approaching this as a linguist, I would hypothesize that we're looking at a system of blocks arranged to form letters...why would someone have these blocks? I would guess that it would be a hieratic script - used only by priests or other high officials. Regular folks wouldn't bother with something as esoteric as arranging blocks.

To get a grasp on the maker's mark I'm talking about, the most obvious example is an ancient script called [Ogham](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogham), which was written primarily on wood or stone. Obviously, writing on stone or wood is difficult, so you'd start by scraping a long line down the center, then scraping lines off of either side:

[image: A weathered example of Ogham]

The two scripts look nothing alike, but they both bear distinctive signs of the method used to compose them. There's a cool story where a linguist walks up to a stone house in Ireland and discovers a gravestone mixed in - the builder assumed that the marks were from the stone cutting.

One other point: if the script is supposed to be derived from Roman times, it should be missing the letters j, v, and y (I'll spare you the geeky details of why). If the timeframe is supposed to be truly ancient, we should be looking at a script based on proto-Indo European, the language from which Latin and most other world languages are descended.

Comment: In the fiction, it would actually be the other way around, and this language inspired Latin, as the aliens were contemporaries of the Romans.

Answer (score 0):

The shapes are reminiscent of both Tsoylani and Hylian scripts, both themselves constructed scripts. (Tsoylani is for Prof. MAR Barker's Empire of the Petal Throne) and Hylian is used in several Legend of Zelda video games.